# How can i find overlapping times in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying for long time and haven't been able to find the logic of how to split the overlapping times in python.

This is my test case times

1. 9am - 5pm
2. 8am-10am,  12pm-1pm, 4pm-6pm  (multiple entries)

**CASE 1:**

```
Entry 1: 9am - 5pm
Test Entry: 10am - 12pm
Output: 9am - 10am,  10am - 12pm, 12pm - 5pm
```

Now i want that if enter overlapping time then system should split it into different times. Like

```
entry1.start_time = 9:00am
entry1.end_time = 5:00pm
```

Now if i enter this entry

```
entry2.start_time = 10:00am
entry2.end_time = 12:00pm
```

Then system should split it into

`9am - 10am,  10am - 12pm, 12pm - 5pm`

**CASE 2**

```
Entry 1 - 9am - 5pm
Test Entry    8am - 10am
Then output should be   8am - 10am ,   10am - 5pm
```

**CASE 3**
This is revese of case 1

`Entry 1 - 9am - 10am`

`Test Entry    8am - 11am`

```
Then output should be   8am - 11am
```

I am stuck at logic . This is bit of code i started

```
class TimeSplitter(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.entries = kwargs.pop('entries', [])
        self.test_entry = kwargs.pop('testEntry', '')

    def test_overlap(self, entry1, test_entry):
        if test_entry.start_time > entry1.start_time and  test_entry.start_time < entry1.end_time
        pass
```

I could not go any further

Comment: You could use 24 H time format then the values can be compared easily.

Comment: In your *case 1*, the `entry2` is inside of `entry1`'s range, thus we split it into three. However, in your case 3 the same thing repeats, `entry1` is completely inside `entry2`'s range, yet we only get one output? What's the deal here?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen case 3 is reverse of case 1. In case 3 entry 1 is inside 2 but in case 1 entry 2 was inside 1st entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prelimininaries**

Given your sample cases, you wish to distinguish the test entry intervals wrt the base entries in the sense that no test entry interval should be split in the algorithm's result.

I will describe a solution in the more general setting first where base and test entry intervals are treated the same. This solution will then be complemented to cater for preserved test entries.

This complement assumes that test entry intervals do not overlap. A second modification makes sure that overlapping test entry intervals are conceptually collapsed into a single interval before running the algorithm.

**Caveat**

This solution does not deliver a shrink-wrapped python implementation but pseudo-code. Turning it into valid python should be straightforward though.

**Outline**

The original time intervals cover a certain portion of the day `p`. `p` is the union of these intervals. Observe that this union is an ordered set of non-overlapping intervals.

The basic idea is to cover `p` by a different set of time intervals fulfilling 3 conditions:

- The intervals cover precisely `p`
- The intervals do not overlap
- No interval boundary of the original set must be an element of the interior of an interval from the new set.

Consider the set of boundary times from the original interval set. The elements from this set are canonically ordered. Build a sequence of intervals defined by adjacent points in time from this set. The result is a gap-free juxtaposition of non-empty intervals containing `p`.

As the `p` may be non-contiguous, the constructed sequence must be intersected with `p` to obtain the final result. This intersection does not
change any interval from the computed set; it may, however, eliminate some.

**Algorithm (general)**

- Collect all time interval boundaries in a list `tl_ta`. The elements of `tl_ta` should be pairs of the actual time and a flag indicating whether the element is the start or the end of the interval. This flag will be used to keep track of the gaps in `p`.
- Sort the list by the first component of the element pairs
- Iterate over the sorted list of points in time constructing the result list of non-overlapping intervals.

  To achieve this you need ...

  - the result list `tl_cover` (initially empty).
  - the current and the previous iteration element `ta_current`, `ta_previous`.
  - a counter `cnt_active` indicating in how many intervals the current point in time is contained (initially 0).

  In each step of the iteration the following operations are performed:

  - If current and previous point in time are different and there is some active interval, push a new time interval on the result list:

    `if (ta_previous[0] != ta_current[0]) && cnt_active > 0 then
      tl_cover.push ( [ta_previous[0], ta_current[0]] );
    end if`
  - If the current time is an interval start, increment the counter of active intervals: 
    `if ta_current[1] then cnt_active++; end if;`
  - If the current time is an interval end, decrement the counter of active intervals:  
    `if !ta_current[1] then cnt_active--; end if;`
  - Update the current and the previous point in time: 
    `ta_previous = ta_current; ta_current = shift tl_ta;`

**Algorithm (complement 1 - stable test entry intervals)**

To keep the test entry intervals intact, maintain a flag `b_preserve` during the iteration that signals whether or not a test entry interval is currently active. While it is, no new interval shall be terminated.

Therefore the tuples from `tl_ta` become triples, the third component indicating whether this point of time stems from a test entry. Processing a test entry start/end time sets/resets `b_preserve`.

`tl_ta` should be sorted lexicographically comparing tuples `(tl_ta[_][0], !tl_ta[_][1], tl_ta[_][1] ? tl_ta[_][2] : !tl_ta[_][2])` such that on identical times, ...

- ... upper interval bounds are processed first
- ... among lower interval bounds, test entry bounds are processed first
- ... among upper interval bounds, test entry bounds are processed last

This convention prevents interference between multiple test and base entry intervals with a common boundary.

The first step of each iteration now also checks for test entry containment:

```
 if (ta_previous[0] != ta_current[0]) && (cnt_active > 0) && !b_preserve then
     tl_cover.push ( [ta_previous[0], ta_current[0]] );
 end if
```

The new variables are maintained together with the active interval counter:

```
 if ta_current[2] then
     b_preserve = ta_current[1];
 end if;
```

**Algorithm (complement 2 - overlapping test entry intervals)**

Instead of a boolean `b_preserve` use a counter `cnt_active_te` initialized to 0 to handle the overlaps. The new check in each iteration's first step:

```
 if (ta_previous[0] != ta_current[0]) && (cnt_active > 0) && (cnt_active_te == 0) then
     tl_cover.push ( [ta_previous[0], ta_current[0]] );
 end if
```

Maintaining `cnt_active_te` instead of `b_preserve`:

```
 if ta_current[2] then
     cnt_active_te += ta_current[1] ? 1 : -1;
 end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally - it's not a good idea to give a complete code - I agree - but here's something, which looks like works. The basic idea is 
1) first take input_start to test_start (if both of them are not equal and input_start is min)
2) always take test_start and test_end
3) take test_end to input_end if test_end is less than input end (and end_input and end_test are not equal).

The code below does that with few bells and whistles.

```
def time_to_int(time_str, midnight_0=False):
    """ Converts a given time to an int. if midnight_0 is passed and is
    True, returns 0, instead of 24
    """
    time_str = time_str.lower()
    if time_str.find('am') > 0:
        return int(time_str.strip().strip('am'))
    elif time_str.find('pm') > 0:
        if midnight_0:
            return (12 + int(time_str.strip().strip('pm'))) % 24
        else :
            return (12 + int(time_str.strip().strip('pm')))
    else :
        return -1

def int_to_ampm(time):
    if(time <= 12):
        return str(time) + 'am'
    else:
        return str(time-12) + 'pm'

# throw in some tests for the above routine
#print time_to_int(' 9am')
#print time_to_int(' 9AM')
#print time_to_int(' 11Pm')
#print time_to_int('12pM\n')
#print int_to_ampm(12)
#print int_to_ampm(11)
#print int_to_ampm(17)

input_entries = ['9am - 5pm', '9am - 10am']
test_entries = ['10am - 12am', '8am - 10am', '8am - 11am']

for ip in input_entries:
    for test in test_entries:
        ip_1 = [time_to_int(x) for x in ip.split('-')]
        test_1 = [time_to_int(x) for x in test.split('-')]
        out_intervals = []
        start = min(ip_1[0], test_1[0])
        end = max(ip_1[1], test_1[1])
        if(start == ip_1[0]) and start != test_1[0]:
            out_intervals.append([start, test_1[0]])
        out_intervals.append(test_1)
        if(end == ip_1[1]) and (ip_1[1] != test_1[1]):
            out_intervals.append([test_1[1], end])
        print ip_1, test_1, "=>",  ["-".join(y) for y in [map(int_to_ampm, x) for x in out_intervals]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I would do:

```
import time

Entry1 = "9am - 5pm"
Test_Entry = "10am - 12am"

#Split the test into hours
hours = Entry1.split(" - ")
Test_hours = Test_Entry.split(" - ")

#Convert the hours into time objects for comparison
hours24 = [ time.strptime(hour, '%I%p') for hour in hours]
Test_hours24 = [ time.strptime(hour, '%I%p') for hour in Test_hours]

#Case 1
if Test_hours24[0] >= hours24[0] and Test_hours24[1] <= hours24[1]:
    print time.strftime('%I%p',hours24[0]) + " - " + time.strftime('%I%p',Test_hours24[0]) + ",  " + time.strftime('%I%p',Test_hours24[0]) + " - " + time.strftime('%I%p',Test_hours24[1]) + ",  " + time.strftime('%I%p',Test_hours24[1]) + " - " + time.strftime('%I%p',hours24[1])

#Case 2
elif Test_hours24[0] <= hours24[0] and Test_hours24[1] <= hours24[1]:
    print time.strftime('%I%p',Test_hours24[0]) + " - " + time.strftime('%I%p',Test_hours24[1]) + ",  " + time.strftime('%I%p',Test_hours24[1]) + " - " + time.strftime('%I%p',hours24[1])

#Case 3
elif Test_hours24[0] <= hours24[0] and Test_hours24[1] >= hours24[1]:
    print time.strftime('%I%p',Test_hours24[0]) + " - " + time.strftime('%I%p',Test_hours24[1])

else:
    print "Error"
```

Comment: i think u missed the point in question. The questions is not about spliiting string into time objects. The time already is in time objects , 9am means start_time and that dash `-` is just for illustration purpose only . I want to know the logic of split overlapping times